# Proper indentation of Clojure's `match` in Emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure

I'm running Emacs 24.5 with Clojure-mode and CIDER and the `match` macro from [core.match](https://github.com/clojure/core.match) is auto-indented incorrectly.

The match clauses are pushed really far to the right, like ordinary function arguments:

```
(match [1 2]
       [1 _] "one"
       :else "two")
```

Whereas a short 2-space indent would be better:

```
(match [1 2]
  [1 _] "one"
  :else "two")
```

What's the usual way to make Emacs indent `match` (and other common special cases) correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say

```
(define-clojure-indent
  (match 1))
```

in your Emacs init file.

This is documented in the README of [clojure-mode](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode); follow [this link](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/tree/5.3.0#indentation-of-macro-forms) for the relevant section as of release 5.3.0.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Apparently it's possible to specify as many special cases as you like in the same `define-clojure-indent` form, which is convenient.